# Can't set the image to imageview from image gallery in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, android-gallery

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
      if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        Log.d("PICK_IMAGE", selectedImageUri.toString());
        Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(this);
        settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_dailogue, null));
        img_in_dailogue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_in_dailogue);
        ImageView img_in_dailogue = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        img_in_dailogue.setLayoutParams(vp);
        img_in_dailogue.setMaxHeight(250);
        img_in_dailogue.setMaxWidth(350);
        img_in_dailogue.setImageURI(Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString()));
        settingsDialog.show();
      }
    }
  }
```

Logcat error

> - java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/232 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.leadconcept.whopopsup/com.leadconcept.whopopsup.CameraActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
> - at com.leadconcept.whopopsup.CameraActivity.onActivityResult(CameraActivity.java:131)

The second logcat error takes me to this line of code:

```
img_in_dailogue.setImageURI(Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString()));
```

What is the problem with that code? I can't understand why I can't send imageUri to an imageview. I also verified that the Uri value I am passing to setImageURI function is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
img_in_dailogue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_in_dailogue);
ImageView img_in_dailogue = new ImageView(this);
```

Aren't you using `img_in_dailogue` (it's "dialogue" btw, not dailogue), before initialising it? Shouldn't it be:

```
ImageView img_in_dailogue = new ImageView(this);
img_in_dailogue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_in_dailogue);
```

HTH.

Comment: yes, its a spelling mistake. i will try this ImageView img_in_dailogue = new ImageView(this);

Comment: if imageview is already in xml why we need to do new ImageView(this).
cant we set the only Uri variable. img_in_dailogue.setImageURI(Uri.parse(selectedImageUri.toString()))